# python delete element from list 1 if it contains prefix from list 2

Tags: python, list, element, contains

I have 2 lists

```
list_links = ['google/order', 'google/faq', 'google/404']
prefixes = ['order', '404']
```

I need to delete all elements from **list_links** which contains **prefixes**

result must be

```
list_clean = ['google/faq']
```

I am trying to do something like this

```
for link in list_links:
    for pre in prefixes:
        if pre in link:
            list_links.remove(link)
            break
```

But it skips some elemets, I think its because i cant remove elemts from list which i am looping at the moment
I have googled a lot examples, but it all with numbers and haven`t worked for me

Comment: Could you show us some examples that didn't work?

Comment: @Prune I'm not too keen on the dupe here because it's too general, while this is comparing against a second list. I also don't think the given answers are the most efficient possible

Comment: `prefixes = set(prefixes)` and then  `result = [item for item in list_links if item.split('/')[1] not in prefixes]` is probably faster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never iterate and delete at the same time, instead use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list_links = ['google/order', 'google/faq', 'google/404']
prefixes = ['order', '404']

result = [e for e in list_links if not any(prefix in e for prefix in prefixes)]

print(result)
```

Comment: Beat me to the same solution, but I think the time complexity can be improved?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all` with `endswith`:

```
list_links = ['google/order', 'google/faq', 'google/404']
prefixes = ['order', '404']
new_result = [i for i in list_links if all(not i.endswith(c) for c in prefixes)]
```

Output:

```
['google/faq']
```

Comment: not sure if `endswith` qualifies as a "prefix"

Comment: @andreihondrari I think the OP's terminology is incorrect, the elements of `prefixes` are really suffixes of `"google/"`